# Firebase Listener Skip

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have converted to Firebase for my Android development as I want to utilise the many features of Firebase (Notifications, Messaging, Storage etc), however, I am having difficulty receiving data from Firebase and cannot find detailed information online. Yes, I have tried the documentation but it does not explain the events I am experiencing.

I want to retrieve all the data that I have an insert it into an arraylist of objects. Here is a static example:

```
users[i] = new User("James" + (i*2.5), "Hmack00" + (i*2), "https://firebasPic_2019.03.03.05.26.35.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=cf", "United Kingdom");
```

Database:

```
   {
      "Users" : {
        "4PdlTlv3qjZ3BmDvrJyUut9Fnq43" : {
          "Country" : "xx",
          "Fullname" : "hh",
          "ProfilePicture" : "htm/o/Images%2FSearchAdapter%2F4PdlTlv3qjZ3BmDvrJyUut9Fnq43%2FProfilePicture%2FProfilePic_2019.03.06.10.47.54.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=b647708e-c6d5-4b45-bef0-3dc40301b73a",
          "Username" : "hmack001"
        },
        "COg4r4io9hezhFpmK3adPucUXA93" : {
          "Country" : "spain",
          "Fullname" : "nat",
          "ProfilePicture" : "hcom/o/Images%2FSearchAdapter%2FCOg4r4io9hezhFpmK3adPucUXA93%2FProfilePicture%2FProfilePic_2019.03.06.19.14.17.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=8620b321-5cef-42f0-a828-dbb7c37c8e7d",
          "Username" : "nat"
        },
        "Tw1xRxViygNsLqrQiaaMAvAduIu1" : {
          "Country" : "uk",
          "Fullname" : "harvey\n",
          "ProfilePicture" : "t.com/o/Images%2FUsers%2FTw1xRxViygNsLqrQiaaMAvAduIu1%2FProfilePicture%2FProfilePic_2019.03.03.05.26.35.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=c290e75a-5f92-4271-bcb5-c644fe1b14ef",
          "Username" : "RGB"
        },
        "vOxr1RoDqgWogKK1lp9pfpTHc6w2" : {
          "Country" : "scotland ",
          "Fullname" : "greg greg",
          "ProfilePicture" : "ot.com/o/Images%2FSearchAdapter%2FvOxr1RoDqgWogKK1lp9pfpTHc6w2%2FProfilePicture%2FProfilePic_2019.03.04.12.30.22.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=27b024cf-0691-4121-8a27-26acf101ebc2",
          "Username" : "greg"
        },
        "xecUOPeyMcQaQrgkU9ouDgK90Ai1" : {
          "Country" : "ggh",
          "Fullname" : "Da apply ",
          "ProfilePicture" : "2FProfilePic_2019.03.03.04.58.50.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=f35854c2-3ff9-4d18-9f7a-10c13f066c68",
          "Username" : "gg"
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is my code and I will explain my errors after (I have left in 'zombie' code, to show the attempts that I have made)

```
//Firebase Variables
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private DatabaseReference myRef;

//Firebase Data
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

        //Firebase Data
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { //Function called every time a change is made to the database
            showData(dataSnapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { //Function called when there is an error in the database/ with the call
            Log.d("Print","Cancelled Firebase: " + databaseError.toString());
        }
    });
}

private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    int userCount = 5;
    int i = 0;
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        //User user = new User();
        //User user = new User(); //Get Count of Firebase Users
        //user = new User();
        if (ds.child(userId).exists()) {
            /*user.setFullname(ds.child(userId).getValue(User.class).getFullname()); //set the full name
            user.setUsername(ds.child(userId).getValue(User.class).getUsername()); //set the username
            user.setProfilePicture(ds.child(userId).getValue(User.class).getProfilePicture()); //set the profile picture

            //Display Information
            Log.d("DataSnapchat Test", "ShowData Name: " + user.getFullname());
            Log.d("DataSnapchat Test", "ShowData Username: " + user.getUsername());
            Log.d("DataSnapchat Test", "ShowData Picture: " + user.getProfilePicture());

            ArrayList<String> userArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            userArrayList.add(user.getFullname());
            userArrayList.add(user.getUsername());
            userArrayList.add(user.getProfilePicture());
            */

            String fullname = (String) ds.child(userId).child("Fullname").getValue();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Fullname: " + fullname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //UserListAdapter adapter = new UserListAdapter(this, R.layout.find_profiles_search, userArrayList, mProfileSearch);
            //mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug the code the showData function is never called and neither functions within the Value Event Listener are called, is this an Async Problem?

Currently I am trying to fetch data and insert it into a variable (Literally any data, once I have a working query I can convert it to fit by manipulating child fields etc).

Question: Does the addValueListener only work  when data is changed in the database? If so then what is the alternative, if not then why are the functions not operating.

I do not recieve any errors and nothing is logged to the console.

I want to put my database into an array list, I know that I shouldnt use getChildren to do this, put I am trying to test if I can get any data before I try and get all the data.

Comment: Are you saying neither your `onDataChange` nor your `onCancelled` is called? As in: if you just put a `Log.d` statement into `onDataChange, then neither of your logging statements is written? That would normally only happen if the device has no connection to the Firebase servers.

Comment: Yes this is what is happening. However I am getting the correct userId from 'getCurrentUser()' and when I debug the code the mAuth variable holds the correct value of the real time database. I am unsure if it is an Aysnc probelm and if it is I dont know how to counter this.

Comment: The myRef variable holds - https://{project name}.firebaseio.com/Users/{userId}. Yet the event listener is never called.

Comment: Sorry, still having a hard time parsing your code so I'm trying to simplify it. The idea is that you run the simplified code, and tell us the result. If you replace the call to `showData` with a simple log statement, does the log statement show up in your logging output?

Answer (score 0):

You have some really weird loops in `showData()`. Since you're attaching a `ValueEventListener` to the node of the specific user, you can just look up the property values for that specific user:

```
myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(userId);

myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d("OnDataChange", dataSnapshot.getKey());
        Log.d("OnDataChange", dataSnapshot.child("Fullname").getValue(String.class));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("Print","Cancelled Firebase: " + databaseError.toString());
    }
});
```