# Firebase Iterate through entire database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to receive all the data from a firebase database, so I can place it into a Users class however I do not know how I will iterate through the entire database as I cannot interger (the i variable in the for loop) insert values into the child field.

My code is this:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists())
        {
            String fullname = (String) dataSnapshot.child(userId).child("Fullname").getValue();
            String country = (String) dataSnapshot.child(userId).child("Country").getValue();
            String profilePicture = (String) dataSnapshot.child(userId).child("ProfilePicture").getValue();
            String username = (String) dataSnapshot.child(userId).child("Username").getValue();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing with: " + fullname + country + profilePicture + username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Count : (4) - " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showProfiles(dataSnapshot);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Database:

```
{
      "Users" : {
        "4PdlTlv3qjZ3BmDvrJyUut9Fnq43" : {
          "Country" : "xx",
          "Fullname" : "hh",
          "ProfilePicture" : "htm/o/Images%2FSearchAdapter%2F4PdlTlv3qjZ3BmDvrJyUut9Fnq43%2FProfilePicture%2FProfilePic_2019.03.06.10.47.54.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=b647708e-c6d5-4b45-bef0-3dc40301b73a",
          "Username" : "hmack001"
        },
        "COg4r4io9hezhFpmK3adPucUXA93" : {
          "Country" : "spain",
          "Fullname" : "nat",
          "ProfilePicture" : "hcom/o/Images%2FSearchAdapter%2FCOg4r4io9hezhFpmK3adPucUXA93%2FProfilePicture%2FProfilePic_2019.03.06.19.14.17.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=8620b321-5cef-42f0-a828-dbb7c37c8e7d",
          "Username" : "nat"
        },
        "Tw1xRxViygNsLqrQiaaMAvAduIu1" : {
          "Country" : "uk",
          "Fullname" : "harvey\n",
          "ProfilePicture" : "t.com/o/Images%2FUsers%2FTw1xRxViygNsLqrQiaaMAvAduIu1%2FProfilePicture%2FProfilePic_2019.03.03.05.26.35.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=c290e75a-5f92-4271-bcb5-c644fe1b14ef",
          "Username" : "RGB"
        },
        "vOxr1RoDqgWogKK1lp9pfpTHc6w2" : {
          "Country" : "scotland ",
          "Fullname" : "greg greg",
          "ProfilePicture" : "ot.com/o/Images%2FSearchAdapter%2FvOxr1RoDqgWogKK1lp9pfpTHc6w2%2FProfilePicture%2FProfilePic_2019.03.04.12.30.22.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=27b024cf-0691-4121-8a27-26acf101ebc2",
          "Username" : "greg"
        },
        "xecUOPeyMcQaQrgkU9ouDgK90Ai1" : {
          "Country" : "ggh",
          "Fullname" : "Da apply ",
          "ProfilePicture" : "2FProfilePic_2019.03.03.04.58.50.jpg.jpg?alt=media&token=f35854c2-3ff9-4d18-9f7a-10c13f066c68",
          "Username" : "gg"
        }
      }
    }
```

I am aware that there is no attempt in this code to retrieve information from all the users fields, I do not understand the logic behind iterating through the database as I dont see where I can do Item 1, Item 2 etc.

Comment: Can't answer the question, but it seems like you might need a relational database back end.

Comment: DataSnapshot has a getChildren method. You can use that to iterate child nodes.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildren()

Comment: The getChildren method returns the number of childs, which is useful however how do I use that number to iterate through the userId's. Also, Jacob, a relational database is not needed...I have the code of my NoSQL database in the question, I just need to fetch all the data from it.

Comment: I think you may want to re-visit the link Doug provided as that function does not return a number, it returns the actual child nodes. And that link also has a code snippet showing how to implement it.

Comment: Are you working on the same project as the user in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064841/firebase-listener-skip?noredirect=1#comment96883279_55064841 If so, you might want to work together with that developer, since the problem seems related, while the code doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
  System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey());
  System.out.println(childSnapshot.child("Country").getValue(String.class));
}
```

Comment: I understand that this will iterate through each node, however how will my String values change?

Comment: if you want to read value as Integer then you have to  
                                          data.child("key").getValue(Integer.class)

Comment: Can you show an example of this? To me, that doesn't make sense the way it has been explained. My string values have the userId hardcoded into them, the question I am asking is how can I remove them and replace them with a digit for item 1, 2, 3 etc. I think what you described is similar but I dont see where Integer.class comes from